# Azure Logic Apps - HTTP Listener

Tags: azure, azure-api-apps, azure-api-management, azure-logic-apps

I am working on Logic apps with HTTP Listener and tried with the below option rather creating API Controller. Referring below URLs

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/app-service-logic-http-endpoint/

I created a Logic App with "HTTP Request" and do the processing and send the response back to caller. It is working as expected.

but one thing i just wanted to know is , when i create HTTP Request, it provides default URL like below,

https://prod-****.logic.azure.com:443/workflows/*******69a5b764/triggers/request/run?api-version=2015-08-01-preview&sp=%2Ftriggers%2Frequest%2Frun&sv=1.0&sig=*****2MCOoTKZU

Shall we define Custom URL instead default one, like below

Please advise.

Comment: If this is the url which is being exposed to the outside world and you want to abstract it yes you can do that using the API management.

Comment: Thanks Tushar. I will verify API management and will do that,

Answer (score 0):

There are two different approaches you can hide the original Logic App URL:

1. Using Azure API Management (APIM)
2. Using Azure Functions Proxy (AFP)

Through APIM or AFP, you can hide the SAS token part of querystring, `sp`, `sv` andd `sig`, as well as the `api-version` parameter. Those parameters can be passed through the request header.

By doing so, you can use your own custom URL and hide the SAS token. I've written a blog post about this: https://blog.mexia.com.au/securing-sas-token-from-azure-logic-apps